# Stage command metadata$filename shows hundreds of occurences of single file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have files in my stage that I want to query, as I want to include filenames in the result, I use the metadata$filename command.

My stage is an Azure ADLS GEN 2.
I have only one file matching the following regexp in my stage : `.*regular.*[.]png`.

When I run the command

```
SELECT
    metadata$filename
FROM
    @dev_silver_db.common.stage_bronze/DEV/BRONZE/<CENSORED>/S21/2715147 (
        PATTERN => $pattern_png         
    )
    AS t
```

I have 562 occurences of the same file in my result.

[image: result data set showing 562 times the same file]

I thought that it was a bug from my IDE at first and double checked on Snowflake's history and this is the actual result from the request.

If I run LIST, the proper dataset (1 result only) is returned.

If I run the following command (the same with any union).

```
SELECT $pattern_png
UNION
SELECT
    metadata$filename
FROM
    @dev_silver_db.common.stage_bronze/DEV/BRONZE/<CENSORED>/S21/2715147 (
        PATTERN => $pattern_png         
    )
    AS t
```

I get the following result.

[image: Picture showing a dataset containing a single result and the regexp, as expected]

In my opinion, this behavior should be considered a bug, but I may have missed something.
For now I will just use TOP(1) because this is fine in my case but it may become a problem in other contextes.

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you SELECT from a stage you are actually reading content of the file using a FILE FORMAT. When not specified CSV file format is used by default.

I think that what you're actually seeing is the metadata$filename information duplicated on every "row" that snowflake can read in your file.

Comment: I tried with a CSV file format with RECORD_DELIMITER being NONE. It worked, against my expectations. So first, thank you ! 
Secondly, I still cannot explain why the result would be different when the request is being UNIONed with another one.

Comment: Because UNION deduplicate data while UNION ALL keeps duplicate.